# Alert Dialogue Box for Forget Password

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

The dialog box just works fine but as soon as I leave an empty field in the textfield ( for email) I get returned back to Login Activity. How can I keep showing the Dialogue Box without going back. How can I create a condition for Empty Email Field.

```
forgetPass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final EditText resetMail = new EditText(v.getContext());
                final AlertDialog.Builder passwordResetDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                passwordResetDialog.setTitle("Reset Password?");
                passwordResetDialog.setMessage("Enter Your Email To Receive The Reset Link");
                passwordResetDialog.setView(resetMail);

                passwordResetDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        final String mail = resetMail.getText().toString().trim();

                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mail)) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Enter Valid Email Address.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        } else {
                            fAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(mail).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Reset Link Sent To Your Email.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error ! Reset Link Not Sent." + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
                passwordResetDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Close The Dialog Box
                    }
                });
                passwordResetDialog.create().show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First i will suggest you to create your own layout of dialog in which there should be close button to close the dialog and then add this line
`passwordResetDialog.setCancelable(false);`
this will prevent the dialog to close and use this function `dismiss();`on the click of that cross/cancel button to close the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you build your own Dialog with your own Buttons
then you can use the button without dismiss

```
    Button b1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_bt_yes);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //your code with no dismiss

        }
    });

    Button b2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_bt_no);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // close dialog
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are using Alert Dialog it's not possible to click the positive or negative button and not finishing the dialog. Use DialogFragment to manage the dialog ensures that it correctly handles lifecycle events such as when the user presses the Back button or rotates the screen. using custom Dialog Fragment it's a bit harder but it's more flexible

see the link to see how to have custom Dialogs:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-dialogfragment